# Crossdomain in python flask won't work

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cross-domain

I am trying to start some communication between flask server and html page. I included crossdomain code as explained here http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/ and it still won't work. Here is my python code:

```
from flask import *
from crossdomain import *
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def pocetna():
    return '1'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8081,debug=True)
```

and here is my javascript:

```
function prebaci(){
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
             if (xmlhttp.responseText==1) document.getElementById("kuca").innerHTML="RADI";
             else document.getElementById("kuca").innerHTML="NE RADI";
         }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","127.0.0.1:8081",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In google chrome error is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load %3127.0.0.1:8081. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

And in Mozzila Firefox:

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the specific error message, it is telling you that you are not connecting to a HTTP server; at least Chrome doesn't think so.

Use:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://127.0.0.1:8081/",true);
```

e.g. use a properly qualified URL.